# Facebook SDK - post to friends wall not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We tried using JavaScript SDK in our website(ASP .net MVC based) to post pictures on friends wall, everything went well but the posted picture is not reflected in respective wall.
Browser console didnt throw any error for this. Meanwhile it worked well in case of posting to own wall and sending picture as a message to others.

Comment: Do you mean posting via API, or using the Feed dialog? (Posting to other people's walls via API is not possible any more.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function FriendsList(hostname) 
     {
$('#fbFriendsListAnchor').trigger('click');
$('#fbLoaderImg').toggle();
$('#fbData').toggle();

FB.api(
    {
        method: 'fql.query',
        query: 'select first_name,last_name,uid,pic_square from user where uid IN(SELECT     uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) order by first_name'
    }
```

Its done with API, I guess